# I want to reverse a string .. please tell me why its not working?

Tags: java, string, reverse

```
import java.util.*;
public class reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        Scanner p= new Scanner(System.in);
        String g=p.next();
        int o = g.length();

        while(i<=o)
        {
            int     q=o - i;
             System.out.print(g.charAt(q));
             i++;
        }

    }

}
```

I get a `Index out of range exception`.

Comment: Indexes for chars are from `0` to `length() -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `i=0` to `i=1`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
        String g = p.next();
        int o = g.length();

        while (i <= o) {
            int q = o - i;
           // System.out.print(g.charAt(q));
            //System.out.print(q); - test line
            i++;
        }
    }
```

You can debug by entering three letter word (Ex: war) uncommenting the `test line`

**case `i=0` output will be :**

```
3
2
1
0
```

Which leads to `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**case `i=1` output will be :**

```
2
1
0
```

Which is the exact output you need for three letter word

Answer (score 3):

If this isn't homework, a more immediate solution is to just use a `StringBuilder` like so:

```
String reversed = new StringBuilder("your string here").reverse().toString();
```

If on the other hand, you have / want to loop, you can do it with a simple for loop:

```
for (int i = o - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(g.charAt(i));
}
```

Your loop generates an out of range exception because `q = o - i` in your case will evaluate to `g.length() - 0` when your `while` loop starts its first iteration. `g.length()`, being 1-based, makes `g.length() - 0` "Out of range".

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out, forgot to add `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

The index goes from `0` to `o-1`, your `i` as well. Thus, `q` goes from `o` down to 1. Better do `q = o - i - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the index correctly, try something like this:

```
int length = g.length();
for(int x = length - 1; x >= 0; x --){
    System.out.print(g.charAt(x));
}
```

We start the the index `length - 1` as it is the last char in a string, and go to index 0